# Changing a DIV class style in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i can do this to change the style of a div ID...

```
document.getElementById('test').style.display = "none";
```

why can't i do this to do the same thing to a class?

```
document.getElementsByClassName('egg').style.display = "none";
```

How do I change the style of a class?

Thanks

Comment: Because `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements, not a single element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements with the class specified. You can set the display to none of the first element:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('egg')[0].style.display = "none";
```

Or loop through the list and set each to the desired effect:

```
var eggs = document.getElementsByClassName('egg');
for(var i = 0; i < eggs.length; i++) { 
  eggs[i].style.display='none'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('egg');
    for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
         elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Note: `elements` is an array, this code loops through it and sets each element style to none.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `document.getElementsByClassName('egg')` is an array.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('egg').forEach(function(b) {
        b.style.display = "none";
    })
```

Comment: It's an `HTMLCollection`, actually.  It's generally usable like an array, but it's live (as in, if you removed the `egg` class from an element, it would magically disappear from the list).

Comment: However, you can use `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('egg'),function(b) {...});`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
function assignStyle() {
  var chks = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
  for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
    chks[i].style.display = 'none';

  }

 }
 </script>
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score -1):

insted of doing all this stuff simply use jquery 
$('.myClass').css({ ...Your CSS properties here... });